# caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have write a public component called `rc-component version0.1.14` which share some public react page across all projects. When I tried to use these component like this in my project:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { withConnect,CommonPageCon } from "rd-component";

const Chat: React.FC = () => {
  return (<CommonPageCon></CommonPageCon>);
}

export default withConnect(Chat);
```

shows error like this:

```
act.development.js:205 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
L @ react.development.js:205
D @ react.development.js:183
we @ react.development.js:1599
t.useMemo @ react.development.js:1650
s @ connect.js:218
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19588
updateSimpleMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19425
updateMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19284
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21673
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:205 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
L @ react.development.js:205
D @ react.development.js:183
we @ react.development.js:1599
t.useMemo @ react.development.js:1650
s @ connect.js:218
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19588
updateSimpleMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19425
updateMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19284
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21673
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1650 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
    at t.useMemo (react.development.js:1650:1)
    at s (connect.js:218:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at updateSimpleMemoComponent (react-dom.development.js:19425:1)
    at updateMemoComponent (react-dom.development.js:19284:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21673:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
t.useMemo @ react.development.js:1650
s @ connect.js:218
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19588
updateSimpleMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19425
updateMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19284
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21673
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Connect(Component)> component:

    at s (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:70620:27)
    at Chat

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1650 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
    at t.useMemo (react.development.js:1650:1)
    at s (connect.js:218:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at updateSimpleMemoComponent (react-dom.development.js:19425:1)
    at updateMemoComponent (react-dom.development.js:19284:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21673:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

this is the index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Chat from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Chat />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

and this is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "config-overrides-path": "src/config/config-overrides.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@textea/json-viewer": "^2.16.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.21",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.30",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "antd": "^5.4.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "rd-component": "0.1.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.6",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

what should I do to avoid these issue? I have checked the lib and my project react version is `"react": "^18.2.0",`. I have checked the versions like this:

```
> npm ls react
reddwarf-tool@0.1.0 /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-tool
├─┬ @ant-design/icons@5.0.1
│ ├─┬ rc-util@5.30.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.5
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @textea/json-viewer@2.17.2
│ ├─┬ @emotion/react@11.10.8
│ │ ├─┬ @emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks@1.0.0
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @emotion/styled@11.10.8
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/material@5.12.2
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.127
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/system@5.12.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ @mui/private-theming@5.12.0
│ │ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ │ ├─┬ @mui/styled-engine@5.12.0
│ │ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/utils@5.12.0
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.5
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └─┬ zustand@4.3.7
│   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ antd@5.4.6
│ ├─┬ @ant-design/cssinjs@1.9.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @ant-design/react-slick@1.0.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @rc-component/mutate-observer@1.0.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @rc-component/tour@1.8.0
│ │ ├─┬ @rc-component/portal@1.1.1
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @rc-component/trigger@1.10.0
│ │ ├─┬ rc-align@4.0.15
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ qrcode.react@3.1.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-cascader@3.10.3
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-checkbox@3.0.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-collapse@3.5.2
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-dialog@9.1.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-drawer@6.1.5
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-dropdown@4.0.1
│ │ ├─┬ rc-trigger@5.3.4
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-field-form@1.30.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-image@5.16.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-input-number@7.4.2
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-input@1.0.4
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-mentions@2.2.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-menu@9.8.4
│ │ ├─┬ rc-overflow@1.3.0
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-motion@2.7.3
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-notification@5.0.3
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-pagination@3.3.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-picker@3.6.2
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-progress@3.4.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-rate@2.10.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-resize-observer@1.3.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-segmented@2.1.2
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-select@14.4.3
│ │ ├─┬ rc-virtual-list@3.4.13
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-slider@10.1.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-steps@6.0.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-switch@4.1.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-table@7.31.1
│ │ ├─┬ @rc-component/context@1.3.0
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-tabs@12.5.10
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-textarea@1.2.2
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-tooltip@6.0.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-tree-select@5.8.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-tree@5.7.3
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ rc-upload@4.3.4
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-redux@8.0.5
│ ├── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └─┬ use-sync-external-store@1.2.0
│   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.10.0
│ ├─┬ react-router@6.10.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-syntax-highlighter@15.5.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0
```

I have already read this document: https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html. This is the sandbox link to reproduce the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-einstein-0b6s66?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Make sure the react versions are same in your project and your library

Comment: yes, I am sure the project react version and lib version is `"react": "^18.2.0",`.

Comment: A npm pacckage or micro frontend

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm i` in both projects.

Comment: I have already tried but did not fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming as you might have installed react 18.2.+ and hence just need to use Chakra version 2. In my case, it was for Chakra ui. Go to the particular version of Chakra. If using NEXT js, be cautious to use as below.

[image: Chakra selection]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).