# Using Component Library with Chakra and React not working inside another React Project

Tags: reactjs, lib, chakra-ui

I have following problem: We have an Web Application with React 18.2.0 and Chakra 2.5.5. We have also build a Component Library. Also with Chakra and React. On top Storybook. Built is the Library with rollup.

if I want to use our Components from our Lib, I have issues like

> "caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')"

OR

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useSyncExternalStore')"

depends on which component I want to use. A simple button component without hooks, is working. But every Component that used a hooks is not working. but its only working with the button if I don't build the lib with components they are using hooks.

I used peer dependencies for the react stuff in my lib and checked also with yarn list or npm list that are only one react version is used. I am sitting for 3 days and tried many different Approaches. tried different rollup configs and so on.... nothing working.

if I got the error inside the developer console I got the message as console.error that one of the options are the reason like the original author

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

---

1. and 3. can I exclude and 2. : should I already got an invalid hook message while developing this component in storybook? I mean if I got the invalid hook message only while using my component inside another project its kind of sus for me.

Here another thread with the same problem of me. but is not answered:

[caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128157/caught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usememo)

maybe you have some tips how I can continue with this research?
many thanks